# Japanese usage or context of the word hakarigoto 謀 [はかりごと] ? Does it have a negative connotation?

Tags: usage

what is the Japanese usage  or  context  of  the word  hakarigoto  謀  [はかりごと]   ?   Does   it  have  a negative connotation ?  Thank you.

Comment: I believe it's typically a negative connotation but that could just be from my experiences with it.  Have you looked for example sentences in any dictionaries?

Comment: It's not a common word. For the neutral sense of "plan" use 計画. You can't go wrong.

Comment: @istrasci,  I looked in the  tanoshi dictionary.  There were no examples sentences. I get the impression it is just archaic though.

Comment: @aguijonazo,  thanks,  i noticed multiple uses  of   計画.  This seems to be  the  most prevalent use for a  "plan."

Comment: It seems like Japanese has a few such words typically for nefarious/cunning plan, like たくらみ, はかりごと, くわだて. Maybe not exclusively for nefarious things, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the built-in dictionary on my Mac:

はかりごと【謀・籌】

① 事がうまく運ぶように前もって作り上げた計画・手段。特に，**悪事**を企てること。計略。たくらみ。「―をめぐらす」

...

So yeah, it's more like a "conspiracy" rather than just a neutral "plan". It comes from はかり + こと, and はかり is the nominalization of the verb はかる.

The verb はかる means to "measure, calculate, etc." and can be written with many Kanji, including 測、量、度、謀、図, etc. When written with the character 謀, it's like the English term "to plot." Surely, when I say I'm "plotting (against someone.)" the connotation is almost always negative.
When はかる is written with other characters though, like 測 and 量, there is no negative connotations.

Comment: Thanks for the research.  Yea,  I noticed the common usage of 計画  (kei kaku)  for  the idea of a plan.  Either in business context or even general planning context.  I did not come across any examples for hakarikoto however.  It sure sounds like it would be used in the context of something on the order of 'conspiracy'  though.  Hhmmm.  I will keep looking. Maybe I will reach out to someone in nihon.  Is there noone from nihon available through this forum though ??

Comment: @keikaku - I'm a native and I've never used this word in my whole life. It's the kind of word you might hear in a period drama. It's not worth your energy.

Comment: @keikaku Another native speaker here. When you enjoy dramas or novels set in ancient Rome, China or Sengoku Japan, where royalty and generals commonly engage in deadly schemes, you will easily come across the word はかりごと. Understanding the meaning of the word is necessary if you want to appreciate literary works without a dictionary, though it's not a word you would typically use yourself.

Comment: @naruto  AND  aguijonazo,  有り難うございました.   yea,  i was watching  one of those history dramas  about the tayu kuranosuke oishi (47 ronin of ako)  and that's exactly what i was thinking.  that is probably where they would use it.  and in the other ones like  account of the shogun guard. and i am sure when get deep into reading classical literature i will find it there also.  本当に有り難うございました !

Comment: As a reminder: don't forget to accept an answer, if it resolved your question.

Comment: @YusukeMatsubara,  how  may  i  indicate that ALL  the responses together  are more than  acceptable  answers  to  my  question ?   because it looks as though the check mark only  corresponds to one answer.

Comment: @keikaku Technically there is only one answer here as of now, so I'd accept it. Comments added below to an answer are not answers in the StackExchange terminology. If you wish to improve the one answer by incorporating comments you found useful, I think you can do that, too, though.

Comment: @YusukeMatsubara,  hhmmm, ok, i will click the check mark.  hopefully people will read and see that i   ALSO  agree with all the other comments.   有り難うございました